# having to compile msgs and srvs first

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, services, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with a large stack that includes some custom ROS messages and services.

Every time I try to compile from scratch, catkin yells at me about not knowing where certain message header files are.

To fix this problem, I do a `catkin_make --pkg` on the specific service package or message package I'm trying to use.

Is there any way to force compilation of those packages first?  It doesn't really make sense that they're not being compiled first to begin with as they're listed as build and run depends in the package.xml's of the packages that complain.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218048/having-to-compile-msgs-and-srvs-first/) by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 350 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some searching for older questions should've provided you with this answer, but just in case: please see [catkin 0.6.15 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » C++ message or service dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-09-22**:
Sorry about that; that's what I needed.  I didn't know what to search for.

Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-23**:
No problem. ROS Answers is sometimes difficult to search.